# Gvim and cscope conflict over Ctrl-T

Tags: vim, cscope

I use cscope with vim and it works great <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for going to a definition) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to pop out of the tag stack. When I tried to use it with gvim, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens a new tab. So I created a .gvimrc file under $HOME, and

```
nmap <C-S-t> <ESC>:tabnew<cr>
imap <C-S-t> <ESC>:tabnew<cr>i
```

and the new mappings work but it does not overwrite the default functionality of C-t for :tabnew. Where can I change that ?

If I cannot change gvim behavior, atleast let me change cscope to using a different key combination so that it does not conflict. Please help !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it @ http://www.mail-archive.com/vim_use@googlegroups.com/msg10540.html

Change cscope to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (letter o) to jump back instead of <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> and all is well.